# Select translator(s) in an efficient way needed for 2 foriegn delegates at a conference

Tags: algorithm

There is a conference going on. There are n foreign delegates. Each delegate knows only one language. There are m translators. Each translator knows 2 or more languages. Also n > m. If no translator knows both languages of the selected delegates, then we need to pick as many translators needed so that translation is achieved.

I am looking for data structure and algorithm for solving this.

I think building a graph with Languages as vertices and edges as translators will do. For given two languages find the shortest path in the graph.

Any better solution?

Comment: I don't think you can get any better than the graph approach you describe. Dijkstra's algorithm is one way to solve it.

Comment: What is the significance of 'n' delegates in this question?

Comment: user1990169, Not sure, I faced this question in Amazon interview.